# Google big query count

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to pull all the customers having less than 4 orders
    in past 3 months in Google BigQuery.

```
SELECT   a.user_id,   b.refer_by, FROM   water_db.tb_order  a INNER JOIN   
     water_auth.tb_users b ON   a.user_id = b.user_id WHERE   (   SELECT
     user_id   FROM
     water_db.tb_order    GROUP BY
     user_id  HAVING
     COUNT(DISTINCT(a.user_id <= 4)))  AND status = 3  AND DATE(a.order_date) >= 
    '2017-02-15'  AND DATE(a.order_date) <= '2017-05-15';------
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you have a question, please include what you are trying to do, what you have tried and the output of it etc.

Comment: are you a beginner?

Comment: yes i am new to this one plz help on this

Comment: here i am trying to pull all the customer ids those are ordered  less than 4 time in the last 90 days

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that each time a record is added to the table it equates to an order but something like:

```
SELECT
a.userid, b.refer_by
FROM water_db.tb_order a
INNER JOIN water_auth.tb_users b ON   a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE 
(COUNT(userid) < 4)
and 
DATE_ADD(MONTH, -4, a.order_date)
```

The date function may differ as I'm not 100% sure what it is in Google Big Query

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to approach this is by selecting from the users table, so you don't need to deduplicate IDs, and just expressing the condition as part of your `WHERE` clause. This should help get you started:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_id,
  refer_by
FROM water_db.tb_users
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM water_db.tb_order
  WHERE tb_users.user_id = tb_order.user_id AND
    status = 3 AND
    DATE(order_date) BETWEEN '2017-02-15' AND '2017-05-15'
) <= 4;
```

In this query, the join is expressed as a correlated subquery involving the two tables. You can try it out using sample data with this query:

```
#standardSQL
WITH tb_users AS (
  SELECT 1 AS user_id, 'foo@bar.com' AS refer_by UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'a@b.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'baz@baz.com'
),
tb_order AS (
  SELECT 1 AS user_id, TIMESTAMP '2017-04-12' AS order_date, 3 AS status UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2017-05-03', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2017-03-13', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2017-02-28', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2017-05-06', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2017-05-01', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2017-05-02', 3
)
SELECT
  user_id,
  refer_by
FROM tb_users
WHERE (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM tb_order
  WHERE tb_users.user_id = tb_order.user_id AND
    status = 3 AND
    DATE(order_date) BETWEEN
      '2017-02-15' AND '2017-05-15'
) <= 4;
```